# How to use MongoDB/DocumentDB/Redis as a side input in apache beam?

Tags: mongodb, redis, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have an use case where I used to get the data through stream (Kinesis), and want to perform some transformation on it. During the transformation, I need to lookup to MongoDB/DocumentDB/Redis, where our reference data is stored. I am implementing this use case through apache beam.

I need to use the collection/tables from these databases (MongoDB/DocumentDB/Redis) as a side input, so that I will load it once and do the lookup from there. I want to load all records at a once and make it available to the side input.

I was trying it, but I am getting below error -

Sample code-

```
final PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> mongoInput = pipeline.apply("Read from MongoDB", MongoDbIO.read().withUri("mongodb://URL")
                .withDatabase("dbname").withCollection("collection_name"))
                .apply("Document to String", ParDo.of(new MongoToKeyValueDoFn()))
                .apply("create a view for side input", View.<String, String>asMap());
```

In class MongoToKeyValueDoFn, I am putting key and value in HashMap and emitting it.

Error -

```
The method apply(String, PTransform<? super PCollection<Map<String,String>>,OutputT>) in the type PCollection<Map<String,String>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, View.AsMap<String,String>)
```

Can someone please point me to load the data in side input?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation on View](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.25.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/View.html):

> If a PCollection of KV<K, V> is known to have a single value per window for each key, then use asMap() to view it as a Map<K, V>

The problem here is that you use `MongoToKeyValueDoFn` to output a `PCollection<Map<String, String>>`, i.e. a PCollection containing Maps, whereas asMap is expecting a `PCollection<String, String>`, i.e. a PCollection of string keys and string values.

The solution here is to adjust `MongoToKeyValueDoFn` to follow the expected format, so it should output key-value pairs instead of storing them in a HashMap.